# Most efficient algorithm for comparing two paths

Tags: speech-recognition, mfcc, hmm, viterbi-algorithm

I'm working with a Continuous Hidden Markov Model, and using the Viterbi Decoder which finds the best possible path for a given sequence. Here is how my algorithm works:

```
1) Process the (input) .wav speech signal
2) Extract the MFCC Coefficients (13) 
3) Use these values to train the HMM
4) Execute the Viterbi Decoder
```

And an example input, after step 4 gives the best path of:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 12 6 6 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 6 4 2 2 6 6 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
8 4 4 2 4 2 2 2 2 6 2 2 4 2 6 2 2 2 2 2 6 2 10 2 6 4 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 2 2 2 
6 10 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 6 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 12 2 6 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 6 2 2 6 2 2 2 
2 12 2 2 2 13 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 8 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 4 
2 6 2 6 6 12 2 2 4 2 12 4 2 2 2 10 4 2 6 8 8 2 2 2 2 12 4 2 2 12 6 2 2 2 8 2 4 
2 4 2 2 2 12 2 2 2 2 4 4 6 2 2 6 6 2 4 4 2 2 2 4 2 4 10 10 8 2 2 2 2 6 4 2 4 2 
2 2 2 4 2 2 4 2 2 8 2 2 2 2 2 2 8 2 6 2 4 2 10 8 4 2 2 8 2 2 4 4 2 2 8 4 2 6 8 
4 2 2 12 2 6 2 4 8 4 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
8 2 2 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 8 2 2 4 4 2 2 2 6 2 4 2 2 2 12 2 2 2 2 4 2 12 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 8 2 2 2 6 12 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I find the best possible path for each of my training data (MFCC) against the model, carried out in the steps above. This gives an ok result when comparing myself, in that, if I enter a speech file "Yes" as input, then, the training for "Yes" will show a very simular path, whereas, if I entered "Yes" as input and compared against training for "No" then the best path will be different.

My question is this: Which would give me the most efficient way to compare the viterbi paths? I have only researched the Euclidean Distance algorithm, as well as the Hamming Distance so would prefer to use these. I know it's a very subjective question, but, I am asking in terms of being able to match two possible paths.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: _Which_ paths do you wish to compare? A Viterbi decoder is an _efficient_ technique for comparing _all_ possible paths through the trellis against each other and returning the best path, that is, it is doing the comparisons for you. In doing the comparisons, the Viterbi decoder doesn't _actually_ generate all possible paths and compare them, but it does a _lot_ of **pruning**, discarding whole bunches of paths by looking at _partial_ paths and then saying for _most_ of them "This partial path and _all_ its continuations cannot be winners and so I don't need to go down this path any farther"

Comment: @DilipSarwate Hi Dilip, thank you for your reply. I think that what you're explaining here is soft / hard decision. I'm not quite sure what you mean.. The algorithm I'm using gives me: `viterbi_decoder(features, model, framesize, q)` in which gives me the output in my post. Obviously, from this, I cannot determine what the sample is saying because I am not comparing this to any training data. I therefore thought I would need some hard / soft decision so my initial thought process was the  Euclidean distance came into.. I've used DTW for a similar process and was thinking of the same structure.

Comment: I think we are talking at cross-purposes. What I described is what all Viterbi decoders do regardless of whether they do soft or hard decision decoding. What you seem to be asking is that you have, say, three waveforms, saying Yes, No, and Maybe, stored as three files which you have used to train the decoder; and now the Viterbi decoder spits out a series of numbers (like the one you posted) that you save in a file, and now you want to figure out whether the decoder output matches most closely with the Yes file, the No file or the Maybe file that was used to train the decoder. Is this right?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes, what you have described is completely right. At the moment, I am processing the (inputted sample), extracting the features (MFCC) and then using these MFCC as training for a HMM model, I then read in the MFCC (training) from the file and put these through the viterbi decoder and now I am looking for is a method which matches most closely with the Yes file, the No file, or the Maybe file.. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried using the Euclidean Distance (squared) so far.. Thank you. Also: The way I'm describing it, is this the correct method for using a HMM?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Do you have any suggestions to what algorithm I should use? Sorry but I'm currently lost as what to use in order to compare the two outputs to find which is the most likely path

Comment: Viterbi decoding should return you the path score together with the path. To make a decision on word you need to select the HMM with the best score.

It seems you don't understand HMM theory at all. Probably you can just read the book like Rabiner "Fundamentals of speech recognition" instead of asking numerous not-well-understood the theory questions here.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks for the reply. I know it seems I know very little (I am learning) BUT the library that I am using [link](http://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/qm-dsp/repository/entry/hmm/hmm.c) line 582.. You would see that it does not return the scoring, just the path.. (I was advised that this implementation would work) any ideas?

Comment: Right, your library is a total crap. Read Rabiner book first, then read HTK Book and use HTK to understand the theory first. Only then you can start your own implementation.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev It's not my library, it's something that someone else has buit BUT the decoder does not return the scoring, it just returns the path.. So I was thinking that I could save the path as a training and then use a measure to compare (similar to DTW).. I don't have the time to re-do everything I have done on HMM - I know it will be a "dirty" way to do this, but, if it works I can then throughly learn about HMM's and implement my own.

Comment: In this library score is stored in phi[T-1][0]. I'm not confident you will be able to understand things without understanding the theory, your previous questions do not confirm that. Good luck

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks for that. But, it still doesn't answer my question regarding whether or not you can use an algorithm to match the best likelihood for a path of the input sample against the path of a training sample to find which is most likely to be the sequence?

Comment: What is a "path of the training sample"? In HMM training many samples are required, usually more than 30. What is the "path of the input sample"? Your question doesn't have any meaning for me.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev If I train the HMM (with the inputted signal) and execute the viterbi algorithm, it will return a path (as stated above).. Assume this is called "Model1" For each training sample (MFCC coefficients) I read these in, and, using the viterbi algorithm find the best possible path for "Model1" which gives me a path (like the one above).. My thought process was to use a feature matching algorithm which passes in these two paths and then determines which is the closest match to the inputted signal. Does this make sense?

Comment: What you are saying has zero sense. Again, I told you don't understand even the basic theory of HMM and trying to ask some question. You need to understand the theory first. HMM is a model trained on several training samples. It contains statistics from the training samples. Then signal is scored against HMM and you get the score which shows how close is the signal to the average of training samples (to HMM). This score is  a single number. HMM scoring is similar to DTW, but you score the signal against the HMM model not against the training sample.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I am still able to use the code I linked you to, though? Please could you recommend a tutorial, or, a insight to the theory (remember, I am a novice in this area) so the more novice friendly the better. so I could atleast gain some theory knowledge. Thank you

Comment: You need to modify the code in order to return HMM score instead of the path. I already recommended you a tutorial for newbie, just few posts above. I saw many other people here also recommended you to try HTK yes/no tutorial.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev So if I train the "HMM" with 30 training files of people saying "Yes" execute the viterbi path, to return the score for this. Then, I enter a file named "yes.wav" in which this is passed through a HMM and scored and if it's close to the score of the HMM, it can be seen as a match?

Comment: You train the HMM HMM1 with 30 people saying "yes". You train another HMM HMM2 with 30 people saying "no". When you get the sample you score that sample with HMM1 and get score1 and with HMM2 and get score2. If score1 > score2 the sample is recognized as yes, otherwise as no.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev So like this? http://codepad.org/1HIx6NCP OR for each HMM should there be a new "model"? Thank you though, your last comment made a lot more sense.

Comment: Like I said, this library is not well designed. It has some limitations:

1. It only allows you to train on a single sample instead of many of them.

2. It doesn't return best path score from viterbi search

There are some issues on how do you understand the code. The number of states in HMM (last argument in hmm_init) must correspond to the number of unique phones for the word (3 for yes and 2 for no) and definitely shouldn't be equal to 1.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I believe the reason (in point 2) of your post is because the author used the paths as a comparison, and not the scoring from the Viterbi algorithm which I know isn't the desired method for doing such process but with the limitations of the training sample, it could provide a a more accurate comparison (in this case).. Or, could you recommend another HMM library (in either C, or C++) that would allow me to train a model using multiple samples?

Comment: I already recommended you the library and many other people recommended you that library too. It's called HTK.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I don't want to use HTK, it's very difficult to understand and implementing - I don't think it's possible to use the MFCC coefficients either, but, I might be wrong?

Comment: @user1582478 I'm confused. Why is the last row incomplete? Each column should have 13 elements right?